По нажатии на кнопку должно с базы данных кидать инфу в чат. Может с авто инкрементом что не так, тк id в базе нет, а вместо него null
По нажатии на кнопку должно с базы данных кидать инфу в чат.  Может с авто инкрементом что не так, тк id в базе нет, а вместо него null
    python
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'main', 'hello'])
def main(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('jokerge.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varcahr(50), pass varchar(50))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    file = open('./photo.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}. Для регистрации введи имя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)

    python
    def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('jokerge.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" %(name, password))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей' , callback_data='users'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь зарегистрирован', reply_markup= markup)

    python
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('jokerge.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    users = cur.fetchall()

    info = ''
    for el in users:
        info += f'Имя: {el[1]}, пароль: {el[2]}\n'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)





попробуйте добавить NOT NULL.

Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

@BenPuls У id после primary key добавить NOT NULL ?
